# Right floated content going under left floated content

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="page_title">
  <div id="left_title>
   <h1> MY LARGE TITLE </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="page_help">
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#page_title
{
  width:960px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#left_title
{
  float:left
}
#page_help
{
  float:right
}
```

When **page_help** div has a lot of content, it goes under the **left_title** and this is not what I want. I want left_title always in the left side of the page_help container.
This picture shows the (non wanted) behavior

[image: non wanted behavior]

And this is what I would like:

[image]

What am I missing in order to have that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the width on the div, then you will get the desired behavior. The problem is that the page_help div is trying to take up as much of the page width as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width of the **#page_help**, otherwise it will try to accommodate for the amount of data you put into it by resizing itself.